# Model deforming when I export it as FBX

Tags: modeling, animation, export

I'm new to Blender and used a tutorial to make the humanoid model. I animated a walk animation and I have an idle animation as well, though when I select the mesh and armature then export it as FBX, the mesh gets deformed. I've tried changing the export settings but I'm having no luck in fixing the issue. Is there something wrong with the armature itself?

Image of problem:

[image]

This is my blend file:

[image]

I would appreciate any advice, I'm still very new to Blender